# Extract lines from file2 that exist in file1 using a loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops, command-line

I am very new at shell scripting and I am having some trouble with the following task:
I want to extract lines from file2 that are found also in file1 and extract those lines to a new file3. I am only allowed to use loops for this (I know it works with the basic grep command, but I need to find a way with a loop)

File1

```
John 5 red books
Ashley 4 yellow music
Susan 8 green films
```

File2

```
John
Susan
```

Desired output for file3 would be:

```
John 5 red books
Susan 8 green films
```

The desired output has to be found using bash script and a loop. I have tried the following loop, but I am missing some lines in the results by using this:

```
while read line
do
grep "${line}" $file1
done < $file2 >> file3.txt
```

If anyone has any thoughts on how to improve my script or any new ideas (again using loops) it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: as you're already using grep, read your `man grep` and try `grep -Ff file2 file1` No `while` loop needed. Note that some versions of `grep` don't support that option, then you should try `fgrep -f file2 file1` . Also note that some `fgrep`s have limiations on the size of file that can be used for the  `-f` argument (and maybe as small as 2K). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Is there any way to do this with a loop (even if it means excluding grep?). My assignment asks specifically for the use of a loop in solving this, so I have been trying to work around that. Thanks again!

Comment: Why the constraint?  Is there a good reason you can't use the standard `join` utility?

Comment: No good reason actually haha but it's for an intro class in scripting and prof only wants this assignment solved with the use of a loop.

Comment: as an assignment, I can see the value of having students understand about reading an input file and processing another file with it. Sorry if I missed that constraint in your unedited posting. I think what you have will work, unless you get a name like "Bobby Boy" ;-) . Run your code thru http://shellcheck.net and fix anything it flags. Good luck.

Comment: Will you prof smile at `while true; do solution_without_loop; break; done` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Bash, you could create an associative array from `File2`, and use that to check membership.  Something like (untested):

```
read -a names <File2
local -A n
for i in "${names[@]}"
do n["$i"]="$i"
done

while read -r name rest
do [ "${n[$name]}" ] && echo "$name $rest"
done <File1 >file3
```

Answer (score 2):

Looping here is a good educational exercise but it isn't ideal for this in the real world.

Technically, this AWK solution works and uses a loop, but I'm guessing it's not what your instructor is looking for:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { find[$1]=1; next } find[$1]' File2 File1 >File3
```

I've swapped the order of the files so the file with the data (File1) is loaded after the file listing what we want (File2).

This starts with a condition that ensures we're on the first file AWK reads (`NR` is the "number of records" (lines) seen so far across all inputs and `FNR` is the current file's number of records, so since this clause requires them to be the same value, it can only fire on the first input file).  It sets a hash (a data structure with key/value pairs, a.k.a. an associative array or dictionary) whose key is the value of the first column (`$1`) on the line so we can extract it later, then `next` skips the later stanza for that input line.

When the code loops through the next file (File1), the first clause does not fire and instead the first column of input is looked up in the `find` hash.  If it is present, its value is `1` and that evaluates to true, so we print the value.  (A clause with no action implies `{ print }`)

---

See [Toby Speight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46282634/519360) for a native bash answer with only builtins.  It uses loops and hashes. You'll likely find that solution is slower on larger data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Awk solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ arr[$0]="";next } { for (i in arr) { if (i == $1 ) { print $0 } } }' file2 file1
```

First we create an array of with the data in file2. We then use this to check the first space delimited piece of data and print if there is a match,

Comment: this is the same logic as [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46287619/519360) and [George Vasiliou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46286035/519360) but with an extra nested loop run once per line of the second file.

Answer (score 0):

With awk :

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1];next } $1 in a' file2 file1`
```

With grep:

```
$ grep -F -f file2 file1
```